# Maven filtering doesn't work with properties in pom.xml

Tags: spring, maven

I am trying to configure my pom.xml file in order to replace placeolders in a configuration file for Spring.

Here is my pom.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>tbetous.spring</groupId>
    <artifactId>blog</artifactId>
    <name>learning-tp-blog</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <java-version>1.6</java-version>
        <env>dev</env>
        <org.springframework-version>3.1.1.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
        <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        [ALL DEPENDENCIES]
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>WEB-INF/spring/application-context-infrastructure-env.xml</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>WEB-INF/spring/application-context-infrastructure-env.xml</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                        <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                    <additionalBuildcommands>
                        <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                    </additionalBuildcommands>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Here is my Spring configuration file (*path : /src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/application-context-infrastructure-env.xml) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

<!-- ${env} is a variable that is replaced at build time by Maven (see pom.xml).-->
<import resource="infrastructure/${env}/application-context-${env}-infrastructure.xml"/>

</beans>
```

But when I try to launch my application after a mvn clean install, I get this :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from relative location [application-context-infrastructure-env.xml]
Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/application-context.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/application-context-infrastructure-env.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'env'
```

And when I look at my application-context-infrastructure-env.xml in the target directory, nothing have changed. I have the ${env} placeholder.

I think my maven filtering doesn't work correctly. Could you help me to fix this ?

Comment: Your resource definition specifies to exclude the file that you are referring to. Is that a typo?

Comment: Also, try adding the resources plugin after your fix the resources declarations.     <plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>2.7</version>
    </plugin>

Comment: Thank you for you help. You can find the solution below. For your information I include my file in a set of files which will be filtered and exclude it from all files which will not filtered. Read more carefully my configuration and I sure will understand. Do not hestite to contact me if you want any further information about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to use the [maven-war-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/).

Example configuration from one of my projects:

```xml
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <configuration>
            <filteringDeploymentDescriptors>true</filteringDeploymentDescriptors>
            <webResources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*.html</include>
                    </includes>
                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                </resource>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src/main/webapp/META-INF</directory>
                    <targetPath>/META-INF</targetPath>
                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                </resource>

            </webResources>

        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Simply adjust the `<directory>` elements.

Comment: Thank you. It works ! However I don't understand my mistake. Why this plugin is necessary ?

Comment: @Elthum - I'm not completely sure, but I think the war plugin is needed because web configuration files aren't the same as Java resources. The latter are located in `src/main/resources`, and web files are located in `src/main/webapp`

Comment: I have tested the same configuration but with all my spring file in src/main/resources. It seems it works without the plugin maven-war-plugin. I think you are right. Thank you a lot for all your answers.