# Recover application name (base file name of WAR) in web.xml

Tags: tomcat, servlets, web.xml

I have some params in web.xml, like this:

```
<context-param>
 <param-name>applicationName</param-name>
 <param-value>app001</param-value>
</context-param>
```

But in same tomcat i can have 3 applications with different names, like: app001, app002, app003. Same application but with name and different bases.

In my tomcat/webapps i have: app001, app002 and app003, is there anyway to get this name and put in param-value in web.xml ? Something like:

```
<param-value>${WEBAPPS.NAME}</param-value>
```

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. Are you asking for base file name of the deployed WAR file? Are you asking for name of the expanded subfolder in Tomcat's /webapps folder? Are you asking for the context path as possibly explicitly configured in Tomcat-specific `context.xml`, possibly provided via webapp? (and available via `getContextPath()` method). Are you asking for the `<display-name>` as configured in `web.xml`? Etc..

Comment: Sorry for ambiguous question. I'm asking for  "name of deployed war file". I need reference this value in web.xml

Comment: Tomcat doesn't support evaluating EL expressions in web.xml (only more advanced servers like JBoss do), but you can get it programmatically during runtime. If you're using Maven as build tool, then you can also use it to fill out placeholders in web.xml the way you expected.

Comment: I'm using Maven as build tool, can you give me some tips to make it with maven ?

Comment: you're asking for tips, here they are: give "maven resource filtering" some attention, and have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31675671/1988304)

Comment: thanks, i got the solution with your help.